# Deleting a Column in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, del

[I use concat to combine two DataFrame.However, the indexes are repeated 0,1,2,3,0,1,2. So, I use reset index to set index from 0 to 6. Now, I want to get rid of the old indexes. I tried df.drop and del['index'] but the IDE says there is no index column. Please help!

[image: data]

Comment: `dfFinal = dfFinal.reset_index(drop=True)`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Comment: Always share code instead of image so that it is easy for others to solve the problem by copying the code.

Comment: @Iovish kumar. thank you for letting me know. This is my first post! Excited to receive help.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
df3=pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!